# Recursivly resolve aliases for tor hidden service with ssh

Tags: ssh, configuration, 15.10, tor

I run a couple of raspberry pis with hidden services on it (for remote access via SSH).

I used to use a .ssh/config to get nice aliases for the hidden services.

Something like:

```
Host *.onion
  CheckHostIP noCompression yes
  Protocol 2
  ProxyCommand connect -S localhost:9050 %h %p
Host node1
  Hostname sadfkadwerwpadf.onion
```

Then `ssh node1` used to work just fine. It would first see that it has to go to sadfkadwerwpadf.onion and then see that all *.onion hosts go to the TOR proxy.

Somehow under Ubuntu 15.10 this has stopped working. I now get:

```
user@host~$ ssh node1
ssh: Could not resolve hostname sadfkadwerwpadf.onion: Name or service not known
```

I also reinstalled everything when moving from 14.04 to 15.10, so maybe I am just missing a package.

Does anyone have an idea what it could be? Or did ssh change the behaviour?

Comment: Does it work if you put everything you have under `Host *.onion` under `Host node1` instead? That should help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes it does work. What also works is `ssh sadfkadwerwpadf.onion`

Comment: Please [edit] and add that information to your question. It looks like the problem is that the `Host *onion` rules aren't applied when you use `node1`. Maybe because the expansion occurs after applying the rules and since `node1` doesn't match `*.onion` before expanding, the rules aren't applied. I'm only guessing though.